# figcaption: only move the text and not the background+text

Tags: html, css, text, background, caption

I am working on a small project about images with captions.

My problem is that I would like to move the text in the caption a bit to the right so add a bit of margin to it. the problem is, when I add margin: 5px; to the figcaption class (Caption), the background moves with the text as well.

Do you guys know how to only move the text while the background stays at the same place?

Here is my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<figure class="Image"> 
<img src="images/batman.jpg" class="gallery" /> 
<figcaption class="Caption">Batman</figcaption> 
</figure>

<figure class="Image"> 
<img src="images/robin.jpg" class="gallery" /> 
<figcaption class="Caption">Robin</figcaption> 
</figure>

<figure class="Image"> 
<img src="images/superman.jpg" class="gallery" /> 
<figcaption class="Caption">Superman</figcaption> 
</figure>

<figure class="Image"> 
<img src="images/wonderwoman.jpg" class="gallery" /> 
<figcaption class="Caption">Wonder Woman</figcaption> 
</figure>

</body>

</html>
```

And here is my css:

```
.gallery {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.Image {
    height: 365px;
    width: 576px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.Caption {
    display: block;
    font-size: 24px;
    width: 576px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #FFFFFF
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding-left` instead of `margin-left` in the `.Caption` class

This will allow you to only move the text to the right instead of the whole block.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `padding` instead `margin` in `.Caption`. In your example, you should use `padding-left: 5px` to only move your text 5px

Answer (score 0):

You can use `box-sizing: border-box` plus padding in `caption` class:

```
.Caption {
    display: block;
    font-size: 24px;
    width: 576px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Or use `text-indent` property:

```
.Caption {
    display: block;
    font-size: 24px;
    width: 576px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-indent: 5px;
}
```